# exif_read_data: keywords decoded incorrectly

Tags: php, exif

I'm using `exif_read_data()` to extract exif data from uploaded pictures. This worked fine on my Windows machine but on my Mac with latest XAMPP all fields seem to be extracted correctly except the keywords/tags. If I look in the file the camera model (which is extracted correctly) is encoded in ASCII it seems (one byte per char). However, the keywords (which were originally edited on Windows (Explorer)) are encoded in UTF16-LE it seems (i.e. ASCII code followed by 0x00). So it seems to be a mix of character encoding.
I tried to force the character encoding to a certain standard (with e.g. `ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'byte2le')`) but most of the times I get question marks in the keywords or nothing at all.

Anyone any idea what's wrong, how to fix it and why this worked fine on Windows XAMMP and not Mac XAMPP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

Forcing `exif.decode_unicode_motorola` to `UCS-2LE` instead of the default value `UCS-2BE` did the trick.

```
ini_set('exif.decode_unicode_motorola', 'UCS-2LE');
```

Still don't understand why it works on a Windows machine without this.